# Check Response Time of HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have a Project, where I need to build a Website HTML5 & JS which gets my current Position after every 30 Seconds. I also want to create a LOG where is stated how much time it took from the Geolocation Request to get the position.

I'm able to create the interval to get the positioning, but have no clue how to implement the LOGGING of the response time.

Answer (score 0):

var t0 = performance.now();

doSomething();   // <---- The function you're measuring time for

var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")